# Index error: List index out of range happens at times

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

So, basically i want to know why this piece of code works at times... Sometimes it works just fine, and sometimes it brings that index error. I have a bidimensional list 4x100 with data. Im simply retrieving data from the third row to sum it all in 1 variable.

Here is the list:

```
a=4
lst = [[] for _ in xrange(a)]
wifi= Wireless('wlan0')
while i<100:
    results = wifi.scan()
    print cont
    print "%-8.16s  Scan completed :" % (wifi.ifname,)
    for ap in results:
        if ap.bssid==AP1:
            lst[0].append(ap.quality.getSignallevel())

        if ap.bssid==AP2:
            lst[1].append(ap.quality.getSignallevel())

        if ap.bssid==AP3:
            lst[2].append(ap.quality.getSignallevel())

        if ap.bssid==AP4:
            lst[3].append(ap.quality.getSignallevel())
i=i+1
cont=cont+1

for j4 in range(0,100):
    num7=num7+lst[3][j4]
```

Comment: please, provide us your `lst` object example on which it fails

Comment: What is `lst`? The contents of it are likely your culprit.

Comment: You're actually retrieving data from the 4th row because your index starts to count at 0. Are you sure `lst` is exactly 4x100? Does `len(lst) == 100` and `all(len(c) == 4 for c in lst) == True`?

Comment: Clearly, because your index is out of range. It is impossible to say more without more details. Check what the output of `[len(sub) for sub in lst]` gives you... that should be illuminating.

Comment: I just added the list, and yes, it must be that, because i know how many data im putting inside the list and i did the rows for the list

Comment: if missing objects in lists don't bother you, you can wrap your `num7=num7+lst[3][j4]` statement with `try-except IndexError`

Comment: also, there is `+=` operator, so simply: `num7 += lst[3][j4]`

Comment: you have user `for ap in results`: in under this condition you have only if condition else is nowhere hence if at any certain point if ap don't match to any of your condition your list will be empty so either create exception condition or use `for j4 in range(0,len(lst)):` instead of `for j4 in range(0,100):`

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been mentioned there is not enough information to tell you exactly why you have the index out of range error.

There are several possible reasons:

1. `wifi.scan()` does not return exactly 4 values in a list. This why the third list in `lst` is not of size 100. Just check the `results` list has exactly 4 values.
2. Not all if statements work due to some reason. You need to check the values of each `ap` item - just print them out and read through the values. The the constants `AP1`, `AP2` etc - are they initialized properly?

Also I would use `elif` statements instead of just `if`. I think it will make the code more readable and nice.

Comment: Thanks guys! theproblem was that the length of each array differed per compilation!